# Word: Select multiple tables and sort by column

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I wonder if its possible select multiple tables from a word file and sort by a column. Usually I select a table and sort with the option sort by a column, but I have multiples tables in my Word file and I would like use a VBA.

I am using a macro to select all the tables but the option sort is disabled:

```
Sub selecttables()
Dim mytable As Table

For Each mytable In ActiveDocument.Tables
mytable.Range.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
Next
ActiveDocument.SelectAllEditableRanges (wdEditorEveryone)
ActiveDocument.DeleteAllEditableRanges (wdEditorEveryone)
End Sub
```

Please any comment I will grateful

**EDIT**

I woukd like that sort avoid the total row

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNJ25.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `For Each` to select each table is the right start. Then sort each table, one at a time, like this example:

```vb
    Dim mytable As Table
    For Each mytable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        mytable.Sort ExcludeHeader:=True, FieldNumber:="Column 1", _
            SortFieldType:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, SortOrder:=wdSortOrderAscending
    Next
```